# Where is the scroll coming from?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is my code for a simple div structure:[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vktechno/2wq6k9ep/1/#)

But there is an vertical and horizontal scroll and it's cause is also unknown.
I also tried to give html and body `margin:0` but the scroll was still visible.
Now if I give margin:0 to `<div class="row flex-grow-1">` i.e. `<div class="row flex-grow-1 m-0">` the scroll goes away.

But I wanted to know why the scroll was generated in the first place and If it can be removed.

Comment: from `bootstrap` use those link and `script`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's from your `class="row"`

```
margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
```

You will need `class="container"` at the parent of any div that has `class="row"` for bootstrap